# How to remote into a password protected server using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, remote-access, winrm

I'm trying to remote into a password protected server using powershell, but it keeps throwing errors.
My code:

```
winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="XX.X.XXX.XX"}
$cred = Get-Credential
New-PSSession XX.X.XXX.XX -Credential $cred
```

and the output:

```
PS C:\Users\user.name> winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="XX.X.XXX.XX"}
$cred = Get-Credential
New-PSSession XX.X.XXX.XX -Credential $cred
winrm : Error: Invalid use of command line. Type "winrm -?" for help.
At line:1 char:1
+ winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="XX.X.XXX.XX"}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error: Invalid ...m -?" for help.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
New-PSSession : [XX.X.XXX.XX] Connecting to remote server XX.X.XXX.XX failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. Default authentication may be 
used with an IP address under the following conditions: the transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials are provided. Use winrm.cmd to 
configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. For more information on how to set TrustedHosts run the following command: winrm help 
config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:3 char:1
+ New-PSSession XX.X.XXX.XX-Credential $cred
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotUseIPAddress,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

My IP address is in the format XX.X.XXX.XX, but I censored it because I have no idea how secure/insecure it is to put that on the internet.

Comment: I see 2 errors. A winrm syntax error, along with `-Credential` not being spaced out.

Comment: Do you know how I would fix this? The credential is spaced in the code, but I made an error when i pasted my censored IP.

Comment: Try `winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="xx.xx.xx.xx"}'` (added single quotes around the JSON)

Comment: thanks! I've moved on to a new error `Error number:  -2144108526 0x80338012 
The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation 
for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and 
configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". 
`